# C# POSTing data to CGI script works if fiddler proxy is on, doesn't work otherwise

Tags: c#, post, proxy, httprequest, fiddler

I need to send data to a cgi script with POST method. If I try my code with fiddler capturing on, it works, if I shutdown fiddler it doesn work. Why this weird behaviour?

The script cgi is on a sms machine that sends SMS. If I run my code from Visual Studio 2019 with external fiddler process running, I correctly get this response: `errno=0&desc=SMS Queued&SmsIndex=4`

If I close fiddler and I run my code I get the error: `errno=2&desc=Destination number missing`.

I've also figured out that if I stop fiddler from capturing http traffic and I set in my code a WebProxy on http://localhost:8888 it works...BUT, if I close fiddler, that proxy shutdown and my code doesn't work any more.

I need to post data with no proxy, how can I do?

I tried both with .NET framework objects and with RestSharp: same issue!
This is my code .NET Framework code:

```
Dictionary<string,string> smsData = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                { "num", number },
                { "text", text },
                { "Push", push.ToString() },
                { "Pwd", password },
};

FormUrlEncodedContent formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(smsData);            

HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://" + ip + "/smssend.cgi");            
httpRequestMessage.Content = formUrlEncodedContent;

HttpResponseMessage res = _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This is my .NET Framework code with RestSharp library:

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient("http://" + ip + "/smssend.cgi");
 RestRequest request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
 request.AddParameter("num", number);
 request.AddParameter("text", text);
 request.AddParameter("Push", push.ToString());
 request.AddParameter("Pwd", password);
 RestResponse response = (RestResponse) client.Execute(request);
 return response.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using TcpClient and NetworkStream